# omitting Spring annotation @ResponseBody causes 404

Tags: angularjs, spring

Within my service if I omit the `@ResponseBody` then this service returns a 404 error but the service is successfully invoked.

Within the logs I receive this exception :

```
.10:00:38.716 [http-nio-8082-exec-10] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/services/myservice/log] in DispatcherServlet with name 'services'
```

Adding `@ResponseBody` is returning data which causes the invoking of the endpoint to not trigger a 404 ?

Here is how I'm invoking the service using AngularJS:

```
  $http({
        method : 'POST',
        url : 'services/myservice/log'
    }).error(function(data, status) {
            alert('Error occurred '+status);
    })
```

Comment: show your spring controller code, this is a backend problem. At least : annotation on the class (and parent if needed) and the definition of the method call (annotations, parameters, type of value returned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a [`@ResponseBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) or annotating your controller class as [`@RestController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) tells Spring to write the handler method return value directly to the *HTTP Response Body*. If you omit that, spring will try to resolve a view and since, i'm guessing, you do not define any appropriate *View Resolver* for that, it will return a *404 Not Found Error*.

Comment: `@RestController` by default assumes that methods are annotated with `@ResponseBody` that is the whole point of `@RestController`.

Comment: Yeah..`RestController` is combination of `Controller` and `ResponseBody`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call from `$http` it may wait for json data return and without `@ResponseBody`, controller does not understand that it should send the object as *json/xml* format. That's why spring complains that there is no path which could handle this request.